# Click a recaptcha when the mouse moves

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the idea:
I'm building a robot for a course, and one thing I think it would be funny for it to do is click the "I'm not a robot" recaptcha (Extremely original, I know).

What I did was made a website where there's a recaptcha that succesfully follows the mouse so that even if the robot moved the mouse, it would still be on the recaptcha. Now, I'm not sure how to click the recaptcha, as everything has to be done autonomously and the odds of the robot hitting the left mouse button are unlikely. I had the idea that since I'm using javascript to detect movement already, why not also have a click fired off from the mousemove event?

Here's the code snippet, full code [here](https://pastebin.com/cKnCgq1Z)

```js
   function click(x, y)
            {
                var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': true,
                'screenX': x,
                'screenY': y
                 });
                 var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
                 console.log(el.dispatchEvent(ev));
               }
            window.onload = function(){
                var bsDiv = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha");
                var x, y;
    // On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                    x = event.clientX;
                    y = event.clientY;                    
                    if ( typeof x !== 'undefined' ){
                        bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                        bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                        console.log(x + " " +y);
                        click(x,y);
                    }
                }, false);
            }
```

```css
  #g-recaptcha{
                position: fixed; 
                margin-left: -20px;
                margin-top: -20px;
            }
```

```html
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <h1> yes14</h1>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" id="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="thisisapublickeybutillhideitanyway"  style="cursor: pointer;" </div>
```

:

In the current iteration I try to make a click() function, but I've also tried bsDiv.click(), bsDiv.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click')), and document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click(), all in the event listener, and none of them click the recaptcha.

I've thought about using something like autohotkey, but I'd really prefer if it was contained in a website as I want group members to be able to use the website easily too.

Comment: I'm fairly sure ReCaptcha will notice that it's not a `trusted` event, and so reject your robot's input. Your efforts would be better spent getting the robot to click the mouse.